Dantzig-Wolfe Decomposition for nurse Scheduling problem
I have the following question. I have a nurse scheduling problem with the goal of minimizing the length of stay of all patients over the planning horizon $K$. We have nurses $J$ who treat patients $I$ and supplementary medication treatment. This defines the nurse-assignment variable $a_{ijk}$ or the supplementary medication treatment $b_{ik}$. The goal of the model is to minimize the length of stay (LOS). This is my model so far:
\begin{align}
\min \quad & \sum_{i \in I} f_i \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & g_{ik} = \sum_{j \in J} a_{ijk} + b_{ik} & \forall i \in I, k \in K \tag{2}\\
& \sum_{i \in I} a_{ijk} \leq Max_j & \forall j \in J, k \in K \tag{3}\\
& \sum_{j \in J} c_{ij} = 1 & \forall i \in I \tag{4}\\
& f_i = \sum_{k \in K} e_{ik} \cdot k - Entry_i + 1 & \forall i \in I \tag{5}\\
& \sum_{j \in J} a_{ij,Entry_i} = 1 & \forall i \in I \tag{6}\\
& \sum_{k \in K} e_{ik} = 1 & \forall i \in I \tag{7}\\
& R_i \cdot d_{ik} \leq \sum_{j \in J} \sum_{m=1}^k a_{ijm} + E_{app} \sum_{m=1}^k b_{im} & \forall i \in I, k \in K \tag{8}\\
& e_{ik} \leq d_{ik} & \forall i \in I, k \in K\tag{9} \\
& e_{ik} \leq \sum_{j \in J} a_{ijk} & \forall i \in I, k \in K \tag{10}\\
& d_{ik} \geq E_{min} \cdot b_{ik} & \forall i \in I, k \in K \tag{11}\\
& g_{ik} = 0 & \forall i \in I, k < Entry_i \tag{11}\\
& g_{i,Entry_i} = 1 & \forall i \in I \tag{12}
\end{align}
Unfortunately, the model is becoming increasingly difficult to solve as the number of instances increases (>4h with an MIP gap of over 40%). Now my question. Is it possible to decompose the model using the Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition? If so, what would the decomposition look like?

All your constraints except (3) are indexed by $i$ and involve variables for one $i$ at a time. That structure is a natural candidate for Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition with one subproblem for each $i$ and with (3) as the complicating/linking constraints.

@RobPratt Thank you. That's what I thought so as well. Sadly I am having a hard time formating both the MP and the SPs. Especially the objective functions. Would you mind sharing how the decomposition would look like?

All your constraints except (3) are indexed by $i$ and involve variables for only one $i$ at a time. That structure is a natural candidate for Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition with one subproblem for each $i$ and with (3) as the complicating/linking constraints.
For the Dantzig-Wolfe reformulation, introduce nonnegative variables $\lambda_{ip}$ and substitute $f_i = \sum_p f_i^p \lambda_{ip}$ and $a_{ijk} = \sum_p a_{ijk}^p \lambda_{ip}$ in the objective and complicating constraints to obtain the master problem:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &\sum_i \sum_p f_i^p \lambda_{ip} \\
&\text{subject to} &\sum_i \sum_p a_{ijk}^p \lambda_{ip} &\le \text{Max}_j &&\forall j,k &&(\text{$\pi_{jk} \le 0$})\\
&&\sum_p \lambda_{ip} &= 1 &&\forall i &&(\text{$\mu_i$ free})\\
&&\lambda_{ip} &\in\mathbb{Z}^+ &&\forall i,p
\end{align}
The reduced cost of $\lambda_{ip}$ is $$f_i^p - \sum_j \sum_k \pi_{jk} a_{ijk}^p - \mu_i,$$
so the subproblem for block $i$ is to minimize
$$f_i - \sum_j \sum_k \pi_{jk} a_{ijk} - \mu_i$$
subject to (2) and (4) through (12).
When you solve the LP relaxation of the restricted master problem, be sure to impose $\lambda_{ip} \ge 0$ (instead of $\lambda_{ip} \in [0,1]$), as discussed in Variable bounds in column generation.

If you further impose $a_{ijk} \le m_{jk}$, introduce the following additional master constraint:
\begin{align}
\sum_p a_{ijk}^p \lambda_{ip} &\le m_{jk} && \forall i,j,k && (\text{$\gamma_{ijk} \le 0$})
\end{align}
The new subproblem objective is to minimize
$$f_i - \sum_j \sum_k \pi_{jk} a_{ijk} - \sum_j \sum_k \gamma_{ijk} a_{ijk} - \mu_i$$

Dear @RobPratt, How is the coefficient $f_{i}^p$ valued? It seems it appears simultaneously as a coefficient in the objective function of the master problem and also as a variable in the pricing problem. Am I missing something?

@RobPratt Thank you for your answer. A further question. Assuming I also have the following constraint $a_{ijk}\leq m_{jk}\quad \forall i,j, k$, which ensures that each patient is only treated by one nurse. Would that be part of the MP as well? I guess j would be another dual vector, which then influences the SP objective function. How would that look like?

@A.Omidi The objective coefficient $f_i^p$ arises from the value of the decision variable $f_i$ in the $p$th solution to the subproblem $i$.

@mingabua It was an error, now corrected.

@RobPratt Sorry for bothering you again, but my supervisor now came up with the constraint $\sum_k m_{jk}=1 \forall j$. Would that be part of the MP or SP? I promise this is my last question.

That new constraint would be in the master problem. Because that constraint involves just master-only variables, the subproblems remain the same as before.

@RobPratt Thanks, so the MP constraint would look like $
\sum_j m_{ij}^p \lambda_{ip} =1 \forall i $ ($m_{ij}$ has the indices $i,j$ and not $j,k$). The duals for this constraints are $\eta_{ij}$. Now the objective function for the SP is: $f_i - \sum_j \sum_k \pi_{jk} a_{ijk} - \sum_j \sum_k \gamma_{ijk} a_{ijk} -\sum_j \sum_k \eta_{ij}a_{ok}- \mu_i$. Am I correct? And does your answer still hold if $m_{ij}$ is defined with the indices $i,j$?

Please start a new question with the new compact formulation.

Off-the-shelf DWR/B&P packages are good for the purpose of testing prototypes.
You can check coluna.jl (see getting started), pySCIPopt (see this answer) or gcg.
There is an abundance of material out there to get initiated, to name a few

Uchoa et al. - Optimizing with Column
Generation (book)

Marco Lübbecke - Column Generation, Dantzig-Wolfe,
Branch-Price-and-Cut  (course)



SAS also provides automated implementations of both Dantzig-Wolfe and Benders: https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_057/casmopt/casmopt_decomp_overview.htm https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_057/casmopt/casmopt_benders_overview.htm

To add on to PySCIPOpt, we expanded on the pricer example for CO@Work2024. You can see the repo containing slides, a README, and code here. Does not go too much into the theory, it's more computational.
